# Setting up a symfony2 dev environement with Vagrant+puppet

Tags: symfony, vagrant, puppet

I'm currently trying to set up a vagrant + symfony2. I followed this [blog post](http://www.ymc.ch/en/vagrant-automated-development-environment-part-2) which relates to this puppet+vagrant config.
https://github.com/jou/vagrant-symfony2-example

I followed the instructions but at the step where I need to curl `http://localhost:8090/app_dev.php/demo/hello/World`, it doesn't work. So I looked into the console output and I found some suspicious lines but it's still hard to say whether it's an actual error. A pasted it [here](http://paste.kde.org/p4e010eed/).

Do you see anything that might have gone wrong during the vagrant up?

Comment: Composer was not able to install vendors

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you mention which line is that please? do you have any idea how it can be fixed?

Comment: I would suggest trying to find another tutorial... there are a lot of things wrong with the github repo that this tutorial is based on... out dated dependencies for composer, not enough memory allocated to the machine in the vagrant file... the list goes on...

Comment: @TKrugg this line `err: /Stage[main]/Sf2_example/Composer::Exec[composer-install]/Exec[composer_update_composer-install]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: php /usr/local/bin/composer install --no-custom-installers --no-interaction --dev
 returned 255 instead of one of [0] at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/composer/manifests/exec.pp:47`

Comment: @MattCooper any recommandations for symfony2?